# Subtraction of sorted data

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a sorted array X[k].
Now I want to find

[image]

I have tried this

```
    int ans=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=k;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<=k;j++)
        {
            ans+=abs(X[i]-X[j]);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the correct answer by using the above solution, but it's not optimized, In some case Time limit exceeded.
Is there any algorithm for implementing this in minimum complexity?

Comment: This problem seems to be a sub-part of a problem from an ongoing contest.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Oh yes agreed. Maybe I shall post my answer a bit later. XD

Comment: @AbhishekBansal But anyway neither you nor anyone is sure about this right? We shall trait it as a normal question `unless` there's evidence that shows not. :P

Comment: @AbhishekBansal : if someone tell me to sort I may use QuickSort or mergeSort because of less complexity. So the purpose of this question is to know is there any Algorithm exists with less complexity to achieve this ? Not in race to win competition. Just for knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

We need to calculate:  `Sigma[i] Sigma[j>i] abs(Xi-Xj)`.  (Indices i,j are assumed to be between 1 and k everywhere).

Because the array is sorted, Xj>=Xi for j>i. This allows you to get rid of the `abs`, so that you have:

```
Sigma[i] Sigma[j>i] (Xj - Xi)
```

This can be separated to two sums:

```
Sigma[i] Sigma[j>i] Xj  -  Sigma[i] Sigma[j>i] Xi
```

For a specific `j`, how many times does `Xj` appear in the first sum? X2 appears once (only for i=1 and j=2), X3 appears twice (i=1,j=3 and i=2,j=3), etc. In general, `Xj` appears `j-1` times, so it contributes `(j-1)Xj` to the sum (assuming 1-based indexing).

In the same manner, `Xi` appears `(k-i)` times in the second sum, so contributes `(k-i)Xi` to the total.

This gives the result: `Sigma[j](j-1)Xj - Sigma[i](k-i)Xi`. This can be simplified to:

```
Sigma[i]((2i-k-1)Xi)
```

This is calculated in O(n), instead of O(n^2) for the trivial algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming here `sorted` means

> For any 1 ≤ i ≤ j ≤ N there is  X <sub>i</sub> ≤ X <sub>j</sub>.

And denote the goal of your calculation as `F`

> let F(X <sub>1..N</sub>) = Σ <sub>1 ≤ i < j ≤ N</sub> |X <sub>i</sub> - X <sub>j</sub>|

Then we have

> F(X <sub>1..N</sub>)
>   = F(X <sub>2..N</sub>) + Σ <sub>1 ≤ i ≤ N</sub>|X <sub>i</sub> - X <sub>1</sub>|
>   = F(X <sub>3..N</sub>) + Σ <sub>2 ≤ i ≤ N</sub>|X <sub>i</sub> - X <sub>2</sub>| + Σ <sub>1 ≤ i ≤ N</sub>|X <sub>i</sub> - X <sub>1</sub>|
>   = F(X <sub>4..N</sub>) + ...

Notice

> Σ <sub>k ≤ i ≤ N</sub>|X <sub>i</sub> - X <sub>k</sub>|
>   = (N - k) × (X <sub>k + 1</sub> - X <sub>k</sub>) + Σ <sub>k + 1 ≤ i ≤ N</sub>|X <sub>i</sub> - X <sub>k + 1</sub>|

So we have the following iteration to calculate the sum:

```
/* 
 * assuming here the data type int is suitable for holding the result
 * N is the array length, X is the sorted array
 */
int sorted_sub_sum(int N, const int *X)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int tmp_sum = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        tmp_sum += X[i] - X[0];
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        ret += tmp_sum;
        tmp_sum -= (N - i - 1) * (X[i + 1] - X[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I've done some simple tests on this code (like the array {1,2,4,9} and {1,2,4,9,17}). Please let me know if you find any mistakes.

**EDITED:** I didn't read carefully the OP's definition and in my answer `N` denotes the array length just like `k` in the original question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a very simple way, `O(n)` time, and as mentioned in other answers, the `abs` function is redundant:

```
int ans = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < X.lengh; i++)
    ans += ((X.length - i) * (i)) * (X[i] - X[i-1]);
```

This method is based on the fact that `X[i] - X[i-2] = 2(X[i] - X[i-1]) - (X[i-1] - X[i-2])`, this allows you to just break every calculation and count the total amount of times the subtraction of two adjacent numbers in the array occur.

Answer (score -1):

We can get rid of abs (array is sorted) and after that In the result x_1 appears (k-1) times as a negative, X_2 appears 1 time positive and k-2 times negative means totally we count it k-3 times negative and .... x_(k-1) appears k-3 times positive and x_k appears k-1 time positive so we have the following simplified summation:

```
int coef = 1-k;
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    sum += coef * x[i];
    coef += 2;
}
```

In the code I supposed the array is zero based index and x[0] equals to x_1 in my description.